# Have snakemake skip rules based on input selection

Tags: config, snakemake

I have a massive Snakefile. The bits that are likely important are these below. I want to make this a bit more flexible with input files.

in the runini file; if lanenumlanelaeve = 1, I want snakemake to start on rule cutadapt (as samples would have been merged already) with corresponding input files, if not follow what normal flow of rules with those corresponding input files. I know an if else needs to placed. But, I am not seeing how to add this/where. Maybe add something in the configfile?

```
# config file
configfile:'rna.config.yaml

# check run.ini file for various things
runini = configparser.ConfigParser()
runini.read('../Run/ini')
ss = runini['File']['SS']

rule all:
   input: complete

def fastq(wildcards):
   names = glob.glob(config['fq_glob'] %wildcards.sampleID)
   return sorted(names)

rule merge:
   input: fastq
   output: 
      'merged_{sampleID}_merged_R1.fastq.gz'
      'merged_{sampleID}_merged_R2.fastq.gz'
   threads: 8
   params:
      r1 = config['pari_id'][0],
      r2 = config['pari_id'][1]
   run:
      r1 = [x for x in input if params.r1 in x]
      r2 = [x for x in input if params.r2 in x] 
     shell('cat %s > {output[0]}' %' '.join(r1))
     shell('cat %s > {output[1]}' %' '.join(r2))

rule cutadapt:
    input: rules.merge_fastqs.output
    output:
        r1 = 'trimmed/{sampleID}_trimmed_R1.fastq.gz',
        r2 = 'trimmed/{sampleID}_trimmed_R2.fastq.gz'
    log: 'multiqc/cutadapt/{sampleID}.cutadapt.log'
    threads: 16
    params: adapter = config['adapter_fa']
    run:
        shell('cutadapt -b {params.adapter} -B {params.adapter} \
            --cores={threads} \
            --minimum-length=20 \
            -q 20 \
            -o {output.r1} \
            -p {output.r2} \
            {input} > {log}')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the snippet you posted if the following would work, since a lot of values and relations have to be guessed. One possibility is to add an explicit python conditional statement along these lines:

```py
if myvar==1:
   rule x:
       input: some_files,
       output: processed_files,
else:
   rule y:
       input: other_files,
       output: processed_files,
```

This type of conditional rule definition can be avoided by having a more wholesome rule definitions, but that would require knowing the full workflow.